# Аргумент типа "char" несовместим с параметром типа "char *"

Tags: c++, c

При выполнении задания выдаёт ошибки "Аргумент типа "char" несовместим с параметром типа "char *"" и "Выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект, но имеет тип "int"", но не понимаю, как с этим бороться.

Код прилагаю. Места в коде с ошибками указаны в комментарии

```
// Выполнить задание через средства языка С (библиотека "string.h”)
// Заданы два предложения и некоторая буква. В каком предложении этих букв больше?

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int lenstr = 10;
const int symbolstr = 1;

// Прототипы функций
void f_input_symbol(char symbol[symbolstr]);
void f_input_1string_count(char symbol, char text_1, int count_text_1);

// Меню
int main() 
{ int count_text_1 = 0; int count_text_2 = 0; char symbol; char text_1; char text_2; int i = 0; unsigned int ans;
  do
  {  cout <<"\n C-language: 1 - input the symbol, 2 - input the 1st string and count symbols, 3 - input the 2nd string and count symbols, 4 - compare; \n C++-language: 5 - input the symbol, 6 - input the 1st string and count symbols, 7 - input the 2nd string and count symbols, 8 - compare; 0 - exit \n";
     cin >> ans;
     switch (ans)
     {case 1 :  f_input_symbol(symbol); break; // Здесь подчёркивает symbol
      case 2 :  f_input_1string_count(symbol, text_1, count_text_1); break;
      //case 3 : f_3(symbol, text_2, count_text_2); break;
      case 0 : cout <<"\n EXIT \n"; break;
     }// switch
  }   while (ans);
  return 0; }
    
// Ввод некоторой буквы
void f_input_symbol(char symbol[symbolstr])
{   
    cout << "\n the symbol is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < symbolstr; i++)
    cin >> symbol[i];  
}

// Ввод предложения №1 и подсчёт символов
void f_input_1string_count(char symbol, char text_1, int count_text_1)
{ 
    char text_1[lenstr];
    cout << "\n the first string is: ";
    cin >> text_1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lenstr; i++)
    {  
        if (symbol == text_1 [i]) count_text_1++; // Здесь подчёркивает [i]
    }       
    cout << "\n It is " << count_text_1 << " symbol '"<< symbol << "' in \""<< text_1 <<"\"\n";
}
```

В С++ новичок, мне нужно написать код без указателей и максимально просто, но я не вижу, где ошибка и откуда char *

Comment: Вот такое объявление аргумента `char symbol[symbolstr]` это объявление *массива*, что по правилам c/c++ эквивалентно объявлению *указателя* (о чем вам и сообщает компилятор).

Comment: Спасибо! Проблему с char и char* решила.
Но вторую проблему понять пока не могу.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int lenstr = 10;
const int symbolstr = 1;

char f_input_symbol() ;
void f_input_1string_count(char symbol, char text_1[lenstr], int count_text_1);

int main() 
{ int count_text_1 = 0; int count_text_2 = 0; char symbol; char text_1[lenstr]; char text_2; int i = 0; unsigned int ans;
  do
  {  cout <<"\n C-language: 1 - input the symbol, 2 - input the 1st string and count symbols, 3 - input the 2nd string and count symbols, 4 - compare; \n C++-language: 5 - input the symbol, 6 - input the 1st string and count symbols, 7 - input the 2nd string and count symbols, 8 - compare; 0 - exit \n";
     cin >> ans;
     switch (ans)
     {case 1 :  f_input_symbol(); break;
      case 2 :  f_input_1string_count(symbol, text_1, count_text_1); break;
      //case 3 : f_3(symbol, text_2, count_text_2); break;
      case 0 : cout <<"\n EXIT \n"; break;
     }// switch
  }   while (ans);
  return 0; }

char f_input_symbol() 
{   
    char symbol;
    cout << "\n the symbol is: ";
    cin >> symbol;
    return symbol;
}

void f_input_1string_count(char symbol, char text_1[lenstr], int count_text_1)
{ 
    cout << "\n the first string is: ";
    cin >> text_1[lenstr];
    for (int i = 0; i < lenstr; i++)
    {  
        if (symbol == text_1 [i]) count_text_1++;
    }       
    cout << "\n It is " << count_text_1 << " symbol '"<< symbol << "' in \""<< text_1 <<"\"\n";
}
```

Ошибки исправлены: переписана функция `f_input_symbol`, переменная `text_1` объявлена массивом.

Comment: Как минимум, вам надо написать `case 1 : symbol = f_input_symbol(); break;`